# Should a teether be given to an infant? If, yes, then at what age?

Tags: infant, teething

The kid is 5 months old. She keeps on chewing her fingers.

Should she be given a teether or should she be allowed to chew her fingers?

What are the possible disadvantages of giving an infant a teether and how should they be countered?

Comment: For what it's worth, my daughter never tolerated a teether.  She preferred her fingers the entire time she was teething (and she got her first tooth at 4 months old!).  Certainly offer one that is appropriate, but be aware she might not be interested.

Answer (score 5):

Give her a teether. Just make sure it's one suitable for her age, but teethers are useful for babies who want to use them and will help her with sore gums.